# Linq 2 Sql and Dynamic table schemas

Tags: linq-to-sql

First a background.  Our application is built on ASP.NET MVC3, .NET 4.0, and uses Linq-to-Sql (PLINQO) as its primary means of data access.  Our web application is a multi-tenant/multi-client system where each client gets their own Sql Server database.  Each Sql Server database up to now has had exactly the same schema.

Often times, clients will ask us to track custom fields in their Db that other clients don't track.  The way we've handled this is by reserving a number of customfields in the db in our main tables.  For example, our Widget table may have a CustomText1, CustomText2.. CustomText10, and a CustomDate1, CustomDate2..CustomDate10 fields.  Again, all our schemas across clients are the same, so Linq-to-Sql handles these fields just as easily as any other field.

Now we are running into an issue where a client wants several hundred CustomBool fields, but doesn't need the others.  So, basically, we are researching for ways to still use the Linq-to-Sql, but have it work against potentially different schemas depending on the database it is connected to (although they are different in a very specific way.)

Too much code has already been built on Linq-to-Sql and accessing the Widget classes generated by it that I'd like to not just fall back to straight SQL.

I've seen answers here and on the web on ways for Linq to Sql to access different tables that have the same schema, but I have not found a good answer to the same table name across different dbs with different columns.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the main objective is to store a few extra fields for *existing* domain objects then why not create a generic table that can store key value pairs. This is extremely flexible since there is no need to change your schema if a customer requires a new property.

We do this frequently and normally have some helpers to correctly cast the properties e.g.

`Service.GetProperty<bool>("SomeCustomProperty")`

If you are looking for a more "pluggable" domain model that can be completely different for each tenant, I think you will struggle if you are following a database driven approach and using the L2S designer to generate your code.

To achieve this you really need to be generating your database based on your code (domain driven design) which will give you much more flexibility i.e. you can load a tenant specific configuration (set of classes, business rules etc.) at runtime and use this to generate/validate your schema.

#### Update

It would be good if you could elaborate on exactly what design approach you have taken i.e. are you using the Linq designer and generating your model from the database?

It's clear that a generic key value pair store is not going to meet your querying requirements.

It's hard to provide a solution without suggesting a different technology. Relational SQL databases aren't really suited for dynamic domain models. You may be better off with a document database such as [MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [RavenDb](http://ravendb.net/) where you are not tied to a specific schema. You could even make use of these *just for* your custom properties.

If that's not ideal then another solution would be to use something like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) to construct your queries. Assuming you are developing against interfaces you can have a implementation of your data service per tenant that makes use of their custom fields.

Ayende did a whole series of posts on Multitenancy and covers tenant specific domain models. It starts [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3494/multi-tenancy) and may be of some use to you.

Comment: thanks.  Yes, we considered using a key/value pair table to provide an unlimited number of custom fields.  The problem is that Linq2Sql does not work with this very easily--for example, for filtering and sorting.  Because these are client specific fields, we use the Dynamic Linq-2-sql library to do things like: query = query.Where("CustomBool10=true and CustomCode2.Code=\"NY\"").OrderBy("CustomCode2.Code").  Linq2Sql happily converts these into the proper Sql statements to fetch the list for the client.

Comment: @Linus you can query quite easily with Linq e.g. `Where(p => p.PropertyName == "CustomBool10" && p.PropertyValue == 'true').OrderBy(p => p.PropertyValue)`. If you need strongly typed queries then perhaps this isn't the best solution for you, so you may wish to look at dynamic models although this does depend on your design approach (as discussed in my answer)

Comment: I understand you can query the keyvalue table, however, the queries get significantly more complex because it is multiple rows for one logical record.  For example, something like "CustomDate10>CustomDate12" is a much harder query to write, and we have those types of queries already in use, which dynamic Linq-2-sql handles very easily.

Comment: We generally build the database schema, and generate the models using PLINQO (really just LINQ-to-SQL under the hood.)  The issue really boils down to the limits Linq-to-Sql imposes on 1-1 mapping.  For example, if I could map the CustomText1..N to an array, we would have been fine.  Anyways, for now we're punting and just adding a bunch more fields to the db.  We can look to other solutions like Dapper or maybe even just plain ADO.NET if we need to address this later, but it is obvious that we've hit a wall with Linq-to-SQL.  Thanks for your suggestions.